# Spark sql subquery

Tags: apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I can't find issue with below query. It keeps complaining about

```
cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'wrk_prd_dt' '.' in expression specification (state=42000,code=40000)



 select tb1.name from dept tb1 LEFT JOIN emp lexp ON (lexp.id = tb1.id)
    where tb1.prd_dt = (SELECT wrk_prd_dt.prd_dt FROM class wrk_prd_dt order by wrk_prd_dt.prd_dt asc limit 1);
```

tried Second approach but same error.

```
SELECT tb1.name
FROM dept tb1 
WHERE tb1.prd_dt >=  (select min(wrk.prd_dt) from class wrk)
limit 1
```

Comment: Side note: in real SQL your sub-query would be `SELECT MAX(prd_dt) FROM class`

Comment: And in plain SQL you would simply JOIN to the sub-query result. Or at least use IN operator so that the optimizer translates as a join.

Comment: As for Spark support of SQL syntax, it depends on the actual version (which you don't mention). But don't expect it to support all the oddities that are specific to SQL Server or MySQL.

Comment: Yes I know about Max() but I am trying to run this query with Spark- hive context.  In Spark max creates Cartesian effect so I am trying to find a better way to do it. As I have copied small part of large complex sql(with multiple left joins). I am using Spark 1.6